# can't find passed data with controller in blade laravel 5.6

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I created a laravel project . I use laravel 5.6

show products and category in balde with bellow code (Products are received correctly.):

```
<div id="orderProductSelect" class="row">

       <h2>chouse product :</h2>

        @foreach($products as $product)
                <div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 10px;">
                    <div id="{{ $product->id }}" class="orderProduct" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <img style="width: 100%;height: 225px;" src="/images/{{$product->filename}}">
                        <span style="display: block;">{{ $product->name }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>


        <div class="categoryAjax" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">

                <h3>chouse category :</h3>

                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 10px;">
                        <div id="{{ $category->id }}" class="orderProduct" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <img style="width: 100%;height: 225px;" src="/images/{{$category->filename}}">
                            <span style="display: block;">{{ $category->name }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

and send product ID with Ajax :

```
jQuery('.orderProduct').click(function(e){
    var productId = $(this).attr('id');
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('order/getCategoryAjax') }}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            id: productId,
            _token: token
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#orderProductSelect').hide();
            $('.categoryAjax').show();
        }});
});
```

I get product Id in order controller . now find product category :

```
public function getCategoryAjax(Request $request){

    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->id);

    $categories  = $product->category()->get();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return View::make('user.profile.order.create')->with(compact('categories'))->render();
    }

}
```

my Product Model :

```
class Product extends Model{

protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'filename', 'description'];

public function category(){

    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'product_id');
}}
```

Now I have error in create.blade.php page :

```
Undefined variable: categories (View: /home/laravel-projects/resources/views/user/profile/order/create.blade.php)
```

Comment: on  which line number, are you getting an error ?

Comment: Thanks . edited question .

Comment: do you have defined category relation with product ?

Comment: You have two divs with `class="orderProduct"` but with different `id`. I guess clicking on one of them won't find any `$product` and thus no `$categories`. Also `if ($request->ajax()) {` should return a JSON response, not a rendered view.

Comment: @Pratik . yes . question edited . add Product Model

Comment: Does that product added with category ?

Comment: You can check 'if' condition for categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a response in this function, not entire view

```
public function getCategoryAjax(Request $request){

    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->id);

    $categories  = $product->category;

    return $categories;

}
```

You can append category from ajax

```
jQuery('.orderProduct').click(function(e){
                var productId = $(this).attr('id');
                var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

                e.preventDefault();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "{{ url('order/getCategoryAjax') }}",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        id: productId,
                        _token: token
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#orderProductSelect').hide();
                        $('.categoryAjax').show();
                        $.each(data, function(index,category){
                            $('.categoryAjax').append('<div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 10px;"> <div id="'+category.id+'" class="orderProduct" >'+category.name+'</div> </div>');
                        });
                    }});
            });
```

In view file

```
<div class="categoryAjax" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">

                <h3>chouse category :</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your Blade you have variable `$products`, but you not receive it from controller

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 10px;">
        <div id="{{ $product->id }}" class="orderProduct" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <img style="width: 100%;height: 225px;" src="/images/{{$product->filename}}">
            <span style="display: block;">{{ $product->name }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks . edited question . I pass product with create function controller . Products are received correctly.

Comment: The error says `categories` though: `Undefined variable: categories`

Comment: Got it. Can you show your Product model in question?

Comment: Are blade code in your questions is `user.profile.order.create`?

Answer (score 0):

First i advise you to rename your relationship from `category` to `categories`. It is one to many, right?
Then you can access to relation only using `$categories = $product->categories` without `get()`.

Also you can try to use `dd($someVariable)` to check any data in your $variables.